# Strange unreachable yet compilable Code

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Well I made this method Resize with in my Class Object2D, which is supposed to resize the two-dimensional Color-Array PointInformation of the Object2D, that it is called onto, by a certain Percentage. (I found that easier to do when convertig the 2D-Array into an 1D Array)

```
public class Object2D

{
int width;
int height;
int ResizePercentage = 100;
Color PointInformation[][];


public void Resize(int Percentage)
{
    Color[]temp = Standart_Methods.Reduce2DArray(this.PointInformation);
    int temp_width = this.width;
    int temp_height = this.height;
    double Faktor = (Percentage+100)/100;
    this.width = (int) (this.width*Faktor);
    this.height = (int) (this.height*Faktor);
    this.ResetPointInformation();
    Color[]temp2 = Standart_Methods.Reduce2DArray(this.PointInformation);

    int SamePixelCount = 0;
    Color LastColor = temp[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] == LastColor )
        {
            SamePixelCount += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i2 = (int) (i*Faktor); i == 1; i-- )
            //Method Resize will only be called when i*Faktor is going to be 100% = X.0 (An Integer)
            {
            temp2[i*2-i] = LastColor;      
            }
            SamePixelCount = 0;
        }
    }
    Standart_Methods.PrintArray(temp2);
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.print(a/b); //No Exeption, Code unreachable!?       
}
}
```

It basically starts at temp[0] and adds 1 to the int SamePixelCount as long as it finds the same Color. 
When a different Color is found, the method writes the Color of the former Pixels into the right Places in the temp2 Array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
    if (temp[i] == LastColor )
    {
        SamePixelCount += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i2 = (int) (i*Faktor); i == 1; i-- )
        //Method Resize will only be called when i*Faktor is going to be 100% = X.0 (An Integer)
        {
        temp2[i*2-i] = LastColor;      
        }
        SamePixelCount = 0;
    }
}
```

The correct translation of the manipulated Array temp2 into the Object's PointInformation is still missing, because I wanted to test, if temp2 was correctly resized out of temp, so I did

```
Standart_Methods.PrintArray(temp2); //the Method works btw
```

but it just did nothing! And even bader! Everything I put at the place of that command, also didn't!

```
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.print(a/b); //No Exeption!
```

And what is even stranger is, that as soon as I call the Method **Resize**, somewhere, everything after the Call turns into the same strange unreachable Code!?

I am seriously totally clueless about what could have caused this problem.

**Any help would be nice!**

Comment: Could something higher up in the call chain be swallowing the exception?

Comment: Then it would at least do Standart_Methods.PrintArray(temp2); wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, and then the `System.out.print(a/b);` would throw an exception after, breaking the flow of execution. If someone did something like `try{myObject2D.Resize(10)} catch(Exception e){/*nothing*/}` you wouldn't see the exception.

Answer (score 0):

dividing by zero certainly will give you ArithmeticException:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 0;
        System.out.println(a/b);
    }
}   

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

I suggest use eclipse and trace your code using the debugger. Inspect your variables per code line and I'm sure you can figure our what's wrong

Comment: Aha , correct in the case you are refering, too. Using double, instead of int would not throw an exception. (Double.Infinity would be the result)

Comment: Yes. At your example it gives you that kind of exeption; but in the context the code is in my example, it doesn't give me an exeption!
I just put the code with 10/0 there do show that this code is not being reached! In fact everything in the place where this statement is, is not reachable!
That was not usefull at all, sorry.